# Передача данных из AsyncHttpClient в Activity

Tags: java, android

На сервер делается запрос, получаю список данных и пытаюсь вернуть их из потока AsyncHttpClient в activity, чтобы передать этот список в ListView. 
Внутри метода onSuccess() список заполняется, но в Activity не возвращается. Догадываюсь, что нужен какой специальный метод  для передачи данных, но что-то до меня никак не дойдет. Вот код:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("user");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRooms);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewText);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        loadRooms(); // здесь я делаю запрос!
        listViewRoomsAdapter = new ListViewRoomsAdapter(this, roomsList);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewRoomsAdapter);

    }

public void loadRooms() {

        String URL = new String("http://*******");
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("token", user.getToken());
        params.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());
        params.put("latitude", "55");
        params.put("longitude", "55");
        params.put("offset", "10");
        params.put("limit", "10");

        client.get(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_FAIL)) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Ошибка");
                        builder.setMessage("Не удалось загрузить список комнат");
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();

                    } else if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_SUCCESS)) {

                        responseArray = response.getJSONArray("response");
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                            Room room = new Room();
                            JSONObject data = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            room.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
                            room.setUsersCount(data.getString("usersCount"));
                            roomsList.add(room);
                        }

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {


            }
        });




    }
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы получаете данные асинхронно, в момент, когда создаётся адаптер в `onCreate`, данных ещё и лист вью остаётся пустым. После того как вы получили данные, вам надо оповестить об этом адаптер, чтобы он перезаполнил лист вью. Делается это методом `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Вызовите его после того, как данные получены в `onSuccess()`:

```
...
responseArray = response.getJSONArray("response");
for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
    Room room = new Room();
    JSONObject data = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
    room.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
    room.setUsersCount(data.getString("usersCount"));
    roomsList.add(room);
}

listViewRoomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Это очень странно, потому что до этого писал так и по какой-то неизвестной причине ничего не получалось. Теперь все работает